# Angular 14 - ERROR: Expected identifier but found "=" - Problem declaring and defining variables at same time

Tags: angular, variables, optimization, declare

Been coding Angular 12 and now 14 for a while...
Created a new application and something has changed that when i run a build it is failing with:
`ERROR: Expected identifier but found "="`

Investigating and it seems the logic for creating a variable is no longer accepted?

previously within a component:

```
    export class MainAppBodyComponent implements OnInit {
        constructor() {}
        ngOnInit(): void {}
        myVar:string = "myStr";
    }
```

This now creates the above error which also provides no method of finding it, the error message complete is:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9J930.png)
Which is a needle in a haystack!

After testing these ALL fail:

```
myVar:string = "myStr";
private myVar:string = "myStr";
public myVar:string = "myStr";
private myVar = "myStr";
```

The only way to get the optimizer to pass is by removing the =

public myVar:string;

And then declaring the value during init... so a complete working example:

```
export class MainAppBodyComponent implements OnInit {
        myVar:string;
        constructor() {}
        ngOnInit(): void {
            this.myVar = "myStr";
        }
    }
```

**My question is, why ? And how can i revert back to the original logic?**
I cant see this change documented anywhere or when it was implemented and no one else is talking about it via lots of google searches...

The core dependancies for the project are:

```
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^14.2.11",
    "@angular/cli": "~14.2.11",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^14.2.0",
```

While checking, worth saying that tsconfig is using es2020

Also worth noting i have another project using same dependencies, on the same laptop which i started January and that does not have this issue and i can happily declare and set a variable at the same time.

Any help, greatly appreciated

Comment: I've never had such an issue (but I only did an update from angular-12 to 15).

But there are other people experiencing the same problem: 

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/23842

Does the error disappear when turning of optimization in angular.json?

Comment: Sorry i should have mentioned, disabling production optimization and buildOptimization does also fix the issue, but obviously not ideal for creating a suitably sized package on build